# jquery open and close of sub navigation that goes two levels deep

Tags: jquery

A js fiddle of the code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/wBLLQ/4/

**Menu Structure:**

```
<nav id="subnav"> <a href="#" class="arrow-button mobile">Sub Nav Button<i class="ss-icon ss-gizmo">&#xF501;</i></a> 
<!-- color class on button -->
    <ul class="sub-nav">
        <!-- color class for sub navigation -->
        <li class="section-home"><a href="#" class="default">Section Home<i class="ss-icon ss-gizmo">&#x25BB;</i></a></li>
        <li class="level-1"><a href="#">Employment</a><!-- active -->
            <ul class="level-2">
                <li><a href="#">Identifying your skills</a></li>
                <!-- active -->
                <li><a href="#">Finding a job</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Employing a person with a disability</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Your rights in the workplace</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Financial Assistance for jobseekers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work experience &amp; volunteering</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- end 1st level -->
        <li class="level-1"><a href="#">Independent Living</a>
            <ul class="level-2">
                <li><a href="#">Identifying your skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Finding a job</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Employing a person with a disability</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Your rights in the workplace</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Financial Assistance for jobseekers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work experience &amp; volunteering</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- end 1st level -->
        <li class="level-1"><a href="#">Education</a>
            <ul class="level-2">
                <li><a href="#">Identifying your skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Finding a job</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Employing a person with a disability</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Your rights in the workplace</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Financial Assistance for jobseekers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work experience &amp; volunteering</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- end 1st level -->
        <li class="level-1"><a href="#">Parenting with a disability</a>
            <ul class="level-2">
                <li><a href="#">Identifying your skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Finding a job</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Employing a person with a disability</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Your rights in the workplace</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Financial Assistance for jobseekers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work experience &amp; volunteering</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- end 1st level -->
        <li class="level-1"><a href="#">Parents of a child with a disability</a><!-- active -->
            <ul class="level-2">
                <li><a href="#">Identifying your skills</a></li>
                <!-- active -->
                <li><a href="#">Finding a job</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Employing a person with a disability</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Your rights in the workplace</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Financial Assistance for jobseekers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work experience &amp; volunteering</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- end 1st level -->
        <li class="level-1"><a href="#">Sport</a>
            <ul class="level-2">
                <li><a href="#">Identifying your skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Finding a job</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Employing a person with a disability</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Your rights in the workplace</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Financial Assistance for jobseekers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work experience &amp; volunteering</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- end 1st level -->
        <li class="level-1"><a href="#">Legal Information</a>
            <ul class="level-2">
                <li><a href="#">Identifying your skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Finding a job</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Employing a person with a disability</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Your rights in the workplace</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Financial Assistance for jobseekers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work experience &amp; volunteering</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- end 1st level -->
        <li class="level-1"><a href="#">Newly Disabled</a>
            <ul class="level-2">
                <li><a href="#">Identifying your skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Finding a job</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Employing a person with a disability</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Your rights in the workplace</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Financial Assistance for jobseekers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work experience &amp; volunteering</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- end 1st level -->
        <li class="level-1"><a href="#">Relationship &amp; Fertility</a>
            <ul class="level-2">
                <li><a href="#">Identifying your skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Finding a job</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Employing a person with a disability</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Your rights in the workplace</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Financial Assistance for jobseekers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work experience &amp; volunteering</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- end 1st level -->
        <li class="level-1"><a href="#">Travel</a>
            <ul class="level-2">
                <li><a href="#">Identifying your skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Finding a job</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Employing a person with a disability</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Your rights in the workplace</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Financial Assistance for jobseekers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work experience &amp; volunteering</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- end 1st level -->
        <li class="level-1"><a href="#">Accessibility</a>
            <ul class="level-2">
                <li><a href="#">Identifying your skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Finding a job</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Employing a person with a disability</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Your rights in the workplace</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Financial Assistance for jobseekers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work experience &amp; volunteering</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- end 1st level -->
        <li class="level-1"><a href="#">Government</a>
            <ul class="level-2">
                <li><a href="#">Identifying your skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Finding a job</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Employing a person with a disability</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Your rights in the workplace</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Financial Assistance for jobseekers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work experience &amp; volunteering</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- end 1st level -->
        <li class="level-1"><a href="#">Transition</a>
            <ul class="level-2">
                <li><a href="#">Identifying your skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Finding a job</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Employing a person with a disability</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Your rights in the workplace</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Financial Assistance for jobseekers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work experience &amp; volunteering</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- end 1st level -->
        <li class="view-all"><a href="#" class="default more">View Menu Itemss<i class="ss-icon ss-gizmo">&#xF501;</i></a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- end sub-nav --> 
</nav>
<!-- end subnav -->
```

**Javascript**:

```
$('#subnav > a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.sub-nav').slideToggle("slow");

    $(".level-1 > a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        if(($(this).siblings('.level-2').is(":visible"))) {

            $(this).siblings('.level-2').slideUp("slow");
            $('.view-all > a').slideUp();
            $('.level-1 > a').not($(this)).parents('.level-1').slideDown("slow");


        } else {

            if($(".level-2").is(":visible")){
                $(".level-2").slideUp("slow");
            }

            $(this).siblings('.level-2').slideDown("slow");
            $('.view-all > a').slideDown();
            $('.level-1 > a').not($(this)).parents('.level-1').slideUp("slow");
        }

        $(".view-all > a").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".level-1").show("slow");
            $(this).slideUp();
        });
    });
```

**CSS:**

```
.sub-nav {
    display: none;
    background: grey; 
}

.sub-nav ul {
    display: none; 
}

.sub-nav .section-home a {
    color: red; 
}

.sub-nav .level-2 a {
    color: green; 
}

.sub-nav .view-all a {
    color: black; 
}
```

**Sub Navigation Functionality:**
When the `Sub Nav Button` button is clicked - the sub nav is displayed, showing all first level navigation items.

If u then click on a first level navigation item:

- it displays the second level of navigation items.
- hides all other non-related first level sub navigation items.
- shows a `view all` button that can be used to reveal all the hidden first level items.

The `view all` button will show all first level items (won't affect a second level item that is shown, if a second level of navigation is open it will stay open)

**The problem** is that when a second level of navigation is open and u close the sub nav. 
when u then open the sub navigation again, and second level items are still showing, it conflicts with my jquery as then clicking on a level one item will open and close all the time.

I'm not sure how to write my jquery in a way that this will not be a problem. Any help would be appreciated. I'm not great with jquery.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understand what the problem is exactly. Could you try making it a little clearer?

Comment: Hi there, the problem is that the navigation works fine unless a second level ul is left open and the whole sub nav is closed, so when it's opened again (as u do the very first time) the difference is that the second level items are showing, which then means when clicking on a level 1 item it opens and closes the second level items immediately, so they dont stay visible, they get hidden immediately - does that make sense? if u play with the fiddle u'll see what i mean, just make sue 2nd level items are showing when u close the whole menu

Answer (score 0):

I don't 100% get your question but you wanna close the 2nd level nav when you click on the "View Menu Items"?

if so you can do this

```
            $(".view-all > a").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $(".level-1").show("slow");
                $(this).slideUp();
                $(".level-2").slideUp("slow");
            });
```

Fiddle updated
http://jsfiddle.net/wBLLQ/5/